# How to drag a folder to the launcher from Nautilus

Tags: unity, launcher, directory

How can I add a folder to the launcher for quick access to it. In this particular case I wish to drag it to the launcher.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. First create a desktop configuration file: `gedit ~/.local/share/applications/folder-shortcut.desktop`
2. Copy and paste the following content to launch nautilus (the file explorer) with the specified folder

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Home Folder
   Comment=Open YOURFOLDER
   Exec=nautilus YOURFOLDER
   Icon=folder
   Terminal=false
   StartupNotify=true
   Type=Application
   OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
   Categories=GNOME;GTK;Core;
   X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
   X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=nautilus
   X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general
   X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.0.0
   X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=nautilus
   Actions=Window;
   NoDisplay=true

   [Desktop Action Window]
   Name=Open YOURFOLDER
   Exec=nautilus YOURFOLDER
   OnlyShowIn=Unity;
   ```

   Replace "YOURFOLDER" with the path to your folder
3. Now navigate to this file graphically from nautilus and drag it to your launcher

Comment: Works. Thanks Marawan. I would remove the sudo from the first line since that folder is owned by the actual user.

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure if it's possible to drag and drop a folder onto your unity bar - but you can have the same functionality with a bit of editing.

- Edit Nautilus .desktop file
  1) In a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) type: `gedit ~/.local/share/applications/nautilus-home.desktop`
  2) If this already exists, edit the following line to add your NEWFOLDER shortcut:

  ```
  X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Videos;Documents;Music;Pictures;Downloads;Dropbox;NEWFOLDER
  ```

  3) Below `X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts` add a new shortcut group:

  ```
  X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Videos;Documents;Music;Pictures;Downloads;Dropbox;NEWFOLDER
  [NEWFOLDER Shortcut Group]
  Name=New Folder
  Exec=nautilus ~/Documents/newfolder
  TargetEnvironment=Unity
  ```

  Where `~/Documents/newfolder` is the location of the shortcut you want to add.
  *(N.B. if this file doesn't already exist you can use a copy of [mine](http://pastebin.com/27kyxHUf).)*
  4) Type into Run prompt (<kbd>ALT+F2</kbd>): `unity --replace`

Now when you right click your home folder/nautilus shortcut you will see an extra option for new folder.

- Create a new .desktop file for your folder shortcut.
  1) Run gedit again: `gedit ~/.local/share/applications/folder-shortcut.desktop`
  2) Fill in the file with a sample as follows:

  ```
  [Desktop Entry]  
  Exec=nautilus Documents/newfolder  
  Version=1.0  
  Name=New Folder  
  GenericName=ew Folder 
  X-GNOME-FullName=ew Folder 
  Comment=Open New Folder
  Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/gnome-computer.png  
  StartupNotify=true  
  Terminal=false  
  Type=Shortcut
  ```

  2) Save the file and open the location in nautilus.
  3) Drag it onto the unity bar.
  4) Right click the new icon and click `Keep in Launcher`

N.B. you do not need to refresh unity for this one.

Comment: Very clever, well done, I thought this was impossible!

Comment: I'm not sure about the second half - it won't drag to the unity bar. But the first half works great!

Answer (score -1):

That's not possible, as that's not what the launcher is for. The bookmarks are displayed in the files lens. If you want an extra bar for your bookmarks, web links, etc, then I suggest adding an xfce4-panel.

Comment: Wouldn't say that's not what the launcher is for. It is essentially a dock of shortcuts (*.desktop). So quite feasible to launch a specific folder location through nautilus.

Comment: No, it is not. Applications actively use the launcher as part of its program. Launcher entries are not static shortcuts. They are program components, with menus, progressbars and counters. Also, they provide keyboard shortcuts to run the application, but also to focus it.