# How do I place a folder onto the launcher?

Tags: 11.10, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to drag a folder to the launcher from Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68962/how-to-drag-a-folder-to-the-launcher-from-nautilus)

There is a folder I need pretty often, and I would like to have a button on the launcher for it. How can I make it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method.  Click the dash and type main menu, click the app to start the editor.  Make a new item in say, Accessories.  click Accessories on the left and on the right click New Item, give it a name and icon of your choice, and in the command box type `nautilus /home/dean/Videos`  for instance, replacing the location with the location and folder name which you want access to.  Click and close the main menu app.  Next, open dash, type the name of your newly added item and it should show up, so just drag it across to the launcher.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a usable way of doing this, as the icons in the launcher are meant to represent  running applications, or applications that can be launched. If you use [duffyduck's method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70760/how-do-i-place-a-folder-onto-the-launcher/70764#70764) you will get confusing results as you will have two icons in the launcher that refer to the same application.

The preferred way to manage a favourite location is to use Nautilus' bookmarks system. Just open Nautilus (the file explorer, the second icon in the launcher), navigate to the selected folder, click Bookmarks, Add Bookmark in the menu.