# How to add a link to unity bar

Tags: unity, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add folders in launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66812/how-to-add-folders-in-launcher)
>   [How to drag a folder to the launcher from Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68962/how-to-drag-a-folder-to-the-launcher-from-nautilus)

I have a link(shortcut) in desktop pointing a folder in my file system. I would like to know is there a way to add that link to the launcher on left in ubuntu 12.04 ?

Comment: If you add the link to `Nautilus bookmarks`, then its available via `quicklists` of `Nautilus`, i.e, in the list you see on right-clicking the `home icon` that you can find in the unity sidebar.

Comment: @Ashu dragging doesn't work...

Comment: @saji89, Thanks for the tip though. I would like to have an app like addition to the laucnher

Comment: @varunit, Ok let me check if there is a way for that.

Comment: Please check the new method I have added to my answer and see whether it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

created my own Desktop Entry specification file and its is working great.. Thanks for the intro

```
[Desktop Entry]
Value=1.0
Type=Application
Name=MyData
Comment=Storage location of all my data
Icon=system-file-manager
Exec=nautilus /host
Categories=System;FileManager;FileTools
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not exactly be the answer you are looking for, but a method to make available the folder in the Unity bar is as follows:
If you add the link to `Nautilus bookmarks`, then its available via `quicklists` of `Nautilus`, i.e, in the list you see on right-clicking the `home icon` that you can find in the unity sidebar.

Check this method:
Create `link.desktop` file with the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Link
Icon[en_US]=system-file-manager
URL=file:///<path_to_your_folder>
Name[en_US]=Folder_link
Name=Folder_Link
Icon=system-file-manager
```

replace `<path_to_your_folder>` with actual path to the folder you need. e.g `/home/username/Documents`
Now drag this file onto Unity launcher and see.
N.B: I'm now in Ubuntu 10.04, so I can't check it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the work. I do have a doubt. Where do I store the link.desktop file?

Comment: @varunit, For now store it in your home folder, and try dragging it to your unity sidebar, and check if it works.

Comment: Okay let me check and reply you back

Comment: I have done as you mentioned. If I double-click, it opens the specific folder, but dragging to the launcher is still not working

Comment: though its not exactly a good method, could you try moving that `link.desktop` file to `/usr/share/applications` (i.e, `sudo mv ~/link.desktop /usr/share/applications/link.desktop`) and then type in Folder_launcher in the unity search box. If you get a result drag that to the sidebar.