# Desktop icon for network

Tags: networking, directory, shortcuts

Very new to Ubuntu 12.04 which I just installed on a laptop but I was wondering how I can get the **folder** in Browse Network to appear on my desktop **and** dock?  Allowing me to be able to click on the folder and the network would be displayed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to get the Network folder shortcut to the desktop, is by using a third-party tool called "Myunity". It is available for free download in the Ubuntu Software Center.

When MyUnity is installed you can launch it either from the dash or from the "System Settings" where a new icon will be created for MyUnity.

To get the shortcut on the desktop you open the MyUnity app, select the "Desktop" tab on the top of app and choose "Show networking Icon".
Now you will see a Network Servers icon on you desktop.

Unfortunately the Unity Launcher does not support adding folder shortcuts by simply "Drag and drop" method.

To add the shortcut to the launcher please see this question:
[How to drag a folder to the launcher from Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68962/how-to-drag-a-folder-to-the-launcher-from-nautilus)

Answer (score 1):

Install Ubuntu Tweaks, a really handy app with a lot of functions/power.  Open terminal and enter:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak

Go to Tweaks-Desktop Icons, trun on "Show Desktop Icons", and click "Show Network Servers" icon.

As for the launcher, Steffen Christensen (the previous answer) has it right.