# How can I add folder shortcuts to the Launcher?

Tags: launcher, .desktop, quicklists

I want to add some folder to the launcher so that I can access them at ease. How do I add shortcut to launcher?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to drag a folder to the launcher from Nautilus](http://askubuntu.com/questions/68962/how-to-drag-a-folder-to-the-launcher-from-nautilus)

Comment: @G_P, he wants a *shortcut*, not a separate icon.

Comment: @JacobVlijm To be perfectly fair the accepted answer in the linked duplicate suggests `Exec=nautilus YOURFOLDER` and  your answer in this question `Exec=nautilus /path/to/thefolder`,  so the two questions have identical answer, which makes them a duplicate. Although yours does add a few interesting points.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Think the question makes the dupe, not the answer. apart from that, many differences in the answer I believe, but its's an old discussion.

Answer (score 25):

There are two ways:

#### Dynamically

You can add a shortcut to a folder by browsing (in nautilus) into the folder you want to add, and choose "add bookmark" from the bookmark menu. Alternatively, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. Bookmarks you created this way are *added* automatically to the `Files` icon in the launcher, in the top section (Nautilus adds these shortcuts to the file: `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`).

#### In the "static" section of the launcher's icon.

Alternatively, you can add a shortcut to the Files icon (or any other icon), by editing its .desktop file. This method gives you more control over the name of the shortcut, and the order of shortcuts, if you have more than one.

- To do that, first copy the .desktop file to `~/.local/share/applications`

  ```
  cp /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop  ~/.local/share/applications/nautilus.desktop
  ```
- Open the (copied) file with gedit; it won't open by double-click, so open a gedit window and drag the file over the gedit window.
- Look for the line:

  ```
  Actions=Window;
  ```

  Add a name that you would like to give your folder in the launcher:

  ```
  Actions=Window;YourFolder;
  ```
- At the end of the file, add a section like this:

  ```
  [Desktop Action YourFolder]
  Name=YourFolder
  Exec=nautilus /path/to/thefolder
  OnlyShowIn=Unity;
  ```

Log out and back in, now you'll have your shortcut in the Files icon by right-click.

#### Explanation:

Icons in Dash and the launcher represent .desktop files. These icons have one "main" command (that's what happens if you click on it), but also *can* have a number of shortcuts (accessible by right-click).

This "main" command can be found in the `Exec=` line, in the section directly below `[Desktop Entry]`, the *shortcuts* are listed in the line `Actions=`, and defined in the `[Desktop Action YourFolder]` - section(s).

.desktop files in `~/.local/share/applications` overrule the ones in `/usr/share/applications`, but the first time after you copy the original to the local directory, you have to log out/in. The clean procedure is always to edit the local one and leave the original untouched.

#### Note:

Bookmarks that you created by the first method, are added to the icon automatically, but are not part of the `nautilus.desktop` file.

---

### Edit for 15.04 *and later*

The answer above applies for 15.04 and above as well, but the launcher to edit (locally copied) for the static section is:

```
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop
```

instead of

```
/usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop
```

Comment: @dushyantashu Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Where do the bookmarks that are created by the first method are kept?

Comment: @LoMaPh They are stored in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`. I added it to the answer.

Comment: Can you add your great answer to duplicate candidate?