# Add a mounted share to launcher

Tags: launcher

Is there a way to add mounted shares to the launcher (Ubuntu 14.10)? I prefer to do it via the terminal, but if there is a easy way to do it via the GUI it's also fine.

My shares are at `/media/*sharename*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not advisable to add a *separate* icon to the launcher, calling `nautilus`. The reason is that then the new icon will "steal" the arrow that you see when an application (in this case: a directory) is opened. The Unity launcher (in principle) only allows one icon at a time to represent an application.

#### Add a shortcut to the Files icon manually

Instead, add the location to the existing nautilus icon, as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/524581/72216).

#### Via GUI

Alternatively, if you'd like to do it via GUI, you could use a quicklist editor, much more convenient:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vlijm/qle
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qle
```

[image]

I wouldn't mention my own stuff, but it fits the question.

Since `nautilus` will be active possibly when you edit its launcher for the first time, you might have to log out/in the first time to see the result (The editor cannot refresh an icon if an application runs).

Answer (score 1):

you can use this tricky solution.

create a launcher on your desktop using the old GUI dialog, run the command

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Desktop
```

[image]

Now In Name write the name of your launcher suppose `ShareMount`

In command entry write the command

```
nautilus /media/share*
```

Then press ok.

Now you have create a .desktop launcher on your Desktop.

To put it on unity launcher easily drag and drop the .desktop file from desktop to unity launcher.