# Add the Apps to the Ubuntu launcher

Tags: launcher

How can I add the applications icon to the Ubuntu launcher?
I have tried in the search engine but I can't find a way to do it.
For example, in mac, you can add the complete apps folder to the bottom bar, and once you click in the folder you will see all the apps.
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Run the app that you want to add to the launcher.
   While an app is running, it can be seen in the launcher.
2. Right click the app icon on the launcher and click "Lock to launcher".
3. Now close the app.It's icon is still present on the launcher.

Comment: First of all thanks, but the thing is that i want to lock the complete Apps folder. do you know how to do it?

Comment: Read [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/68962/how-to-drag-a-folder-to-the-launcher-from-nautilus).

Comment: My gimp doesn't work like that. The launcher is indicated as script-fu every time I do your method.